# Get phone number of current call on iphone

Tags: iphone, logging, phone-call

Is it possible to get phone number of a call during that call? Or, at least, get the phone number of the last received call?

Comment: (1) Why? (2) What if the user never dialed a number, or using an iPod?

Answer (score 1):

No. Allowing that could cause security issues.

Comment: there is a possibility to retrieve the last call status by using Core Telephony API. Could it help in this issue?

Comment: Yes, but not when the question was asked nearly a year ago. Core Telephony is part of iOS4 which was not introduced yet at that time.